# how to read Data context parameter from a crm to silverlight webresource

Tags: silverlight-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, webresource

i have a silverlight webresource in my crm 2011. 
now my task is to append a data parameter in url like

```
https://www.............../data=1234
```

now in silverlight application i need to read this data parameter.
i have tried to read the data

```
  if (App.Current.Host.InitParams["data"] != string.Empty)
            {
                string CallerNumber = App.Current.Host.InitParams["data"];

...
```

and

i tried filtering the code to like

```
string url = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.ToString();
            var uri = new Uri(url);
            var CallerNumber = uri.Query;
```

callernumber will have the ?data=1234

but still i am not able to get the data parameter. Do help

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you will find those in the query string. You can access it like this

```
foreach (var item in HtmlPage.Document.QueryString)
{
    //Do something like the data
}
```